# IgnitedTables | Filtering on Group Concat gives Error

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatables

I am using Ignited Tables for Datatables in Codeigniter,
The issue i am facing is that ignited Tables dont have proper support for Group Concat, as i am using Group Concat, I get MySQL error.

```
Error Number: 1111

Invalid use of group function

SELECT `E`.`employee_id`, `E`.`full_name`, `MLD`.`designation_name`, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT MLP.project_title) AS Projects, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT MLST.skill_name) AS EmployeeSkills FROM (`emp_skills` ES) INNER JOIN `employee` E ON `E`.`employee_id`= `ES`.`employee_id` INNER JOIN `ml_skill_type` MLST ON `MLST`.`skill_type_id` = `ES`.`ml_skill_type_id` INNER JOIN `employment` ET ON `ET`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id` INNER JOIN `position_management` PM ON `PM`.`employement_id`=`ET`.`employment_id` AND PM.current=1 INNER JOIN `ml_designations` MLD ON `MLD`.`ml_designation_id`=`PM`.`ml_designation_id` LEFT JOIN `assign_job` AJ ON `AJ`.`employee_id` = `E`.`employee_id` LEFT JOIN `ml_projects` MLP ON `MLP`.`project_id` = `AJ`.`project_id` WHERE (E.full_name LIKE '%s%' OR MLD.designation_name LIKE '%s%' OR GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT MLP.project_title) LIKE '%s%' OR GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT MLST.skill_name) LIKE '%s%' ) GROUP BY `E`.`employee_id` LIMIT 25

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\projects\HR\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Im using version 0.7 of ignited tables, but still in ver 2.0 i dont see any support for group concat, i would have updated to version 2.0 but i get error, when ever i try to update from ver 0.7 to 2.0 of ignited tables.

DataTables library that I use:
    https://github.com/pakistanihaider/HouseRentSystem/blob/master/application/libraries/Datatables.php

Any Fix for Group Concat that i can have in my library to fix the filtering in datatables?

---

There is a solution on github, as this issue has been raised before. but its not the permanent solution, as if used this solution then filters only works for group_concats if present in table and other simple tables are not filtered.

But if there is no group concat then it is fine..

Now how to have filter work on both group_concat columns and simple columns together.?

---

Just Found Out there is an issue with the total results and pagination if used Group_Concat.. :(
and i have to use datatables as whole project is built using datatables..

[image]

Any one familiar with ignited tables library??
https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/issues/76

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm also experiencing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Just overturn it by not including the column with `GROUP_CONCAT` into the searchable.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#your-table').dataTable({
    "columnDefs": [{
      "bSearchable": false,
      "render": function(data, type, row) {
        //if you had any rendering
        return data;
      },
      "targets": 3 //column with the group concat
    }]
  });
});
```